# django how to filter through a ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I've got the models:

```
class DamageKind(models.Model):
    # the possible regions for this kind of damage
    regions = models.ManyToManyField(Region)
    [...]

class Damage(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region)
    kind = forms.models.ModelChoiceField(queryset=???)
    [...]
```

how I can get the queryset that only contains the damagekinds that are possible for the selectet region?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `Damage` supposed to be a model or a form?

Comment: I guess a model, but because it is my first project with Django so I don't exactly know the difference, I'm just guessing that this is the right way

Comment: Then you should read the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/

Comment: ok, but what would be the solution if it is a normal model and no form?

Comment: you can't  use forms.models, also if you want to use relation, you have to refer to the model, not to the field